# No se ha podido encontrar la dirección IP del servidor de xxx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Estoy configurando una web asp.net dentro de un IIS(Internet Information Services), he subido mi web generando un nuevo sitio y configurándolo, no se exactamente que puede estar fallando pero al intentar acceder me salta el mensaje:

> No se ha podido encontrar la dirección IP del servidor de xxx

Los pasos que he seguido para instalar la web han sido:

1. Realizar una publicación de la propia.
2. Dentro del IIS agregar un sitio web.
3. Nombrar el sitio y asignarle un grupo de aplicaciones.
4. Asignar el directorio de contenido.
5. asignar puerto
6. asignar nombre de host.

Despues de eso en teoria debería poder acceder pero en chrome me salta el mensaje de error anterior.

**Edición**

Viendo [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033434/server-dns-address-could-not-be-found-iis) y accediendo a:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

como administrador y añadiendo:

```
127.0.0.1    xxxx
```

Salta un nuevo error de 
**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

**¿Que me falta?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preguntando por el chat, descubrimos que al atacar a `127.0.0.1` si que mostraba la web por defecto, pero al añadir el puerto asignado bloqueaba la web, asi que los pasos que seguí fueron:

1. Acceder al firewall.
2. Escribir una nueva regla de entrada.
3. Seleccionar la opcion de puerto TCP UDP.
4. Asignar el puerto
5. Siguiente y siguiente y finalizar.

Reiniciar la web y ejecutar. Todo funciona.